# Is using TrueCrypt in OSX secure?

Tags: encryption

What would be a more secure way to encrypt files using TrueCrypt 7.1a. The is an airgapped computer (wifi, bluetooth, speakers and mic removed too). The encrypted files will be on an external drive in either setup and not on the system's HDD.

1. An FDE TrueCrypt notebook running Windows.
2. A MacBook running OSX but without TrueCrypt FDE (not available) but running TrueCrypt in the OS to encrypt the files on an external drive.

The second setup would be more user friendly to me but are there any dangers in this setup if the encrypted drive is unmounted. I'm afraid of leaving keys or info behind that would compromise the external TrueCrypt encrypted drive.

Comment: [Secure against what?](https://ssd.eff.org/en/playlist/activist-or-protester#introduction-threat-modeling) (Note that the linked article is general, and not specific to the "activist or protester" category of people.)

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer a broad question as "is it secure?" So I will answer a more specific but related question:

"Am I safe from widely known security vulnerabilities in using TrueCrypt on OS X?"

As far as I know, the current answer is **yes**. If you do decide to go with TrueCrypt, you should keep monitoring this page: [IsTrueCryptAuditedYet](http://istruecryptauditedyet.com/)

For an alternative, you can [set up CoreStorage encryption](http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/encrypting-10-7-non-boot-volumes-without-erasing-them/) on OS X -- if you don't need your disk to be compatible to Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Even though TrueCrypt has been discontinued, I've never seen prove that a full encrypted disk can be (easily) recovered.

As an alternative for both Windows and Mac, consider using BestCrypt: http://www.jetico.com/products/personal-privacy/bestcrypt-volume-encryption (Paid)

A comparison of disk encryption software can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_disk_encryption_software (section Operating Systems)